# Linking error using soci 3.2.3 instead of 3.2.2

Tags: c++, visual-c++, soci

I have a project which uses soci for DB access. The project was originally developed with soci 3.2.2.
Now I switched to soci 3.2.3 and get the following linker error messages:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class soci::details::once_temp_type & __thiscall soci::details::once_temp_type::operator,(class soci::details::type_ptr<class soci::details::use_type_base> const &)" (??Qonce_temp_type@details@soci@@QAEAAV012@ABV?$type_ptr@Vuse_type_base@details@soci@@@12@@Z)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall  soci::details::statement_impl::exchange_for_rowset(class soci::details::type_ptr<class soci::details::into_type_base> const &)" (?exchange_for_rowset@statement_impl@details@soci@@QAEXABV?$type_ptr@Vinto_type_base@details@soci@@@23@@Z)

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class soci::details::prepare_temp_type & __thiscall soci::details::prepare_temp_type::operator,(class soci::details::type_ptr<class soci::details::use_type_base> const &)" (??Qprepare_temp_type@details@soci@@QAEAAV012@ABV?$type_ptr@Vuse_type_base@details@soci@@@12@@Z)
```

I use Visual Studio 2010 on a Windows machine.
Does somebody has an idea what could be the issue?

Bests

Comment: After changing version of the library, did you rebuild the code as well?

Comment: Yes, I cleaned and rebuilded the solution as well as the included projects (2).

Comment: Interestingly, debug build works. Only release build does not work.

Comment: Sounds like wrong include paths in project properties. Something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I have to withdraw the last comment. Building debug works since I haven't linked there to soci 3.2.3. Old version is linked there.

Comment: I hope you have the two versions separated in different folders. If so, rename 3.2.2 folder to make sure no .h file there will be used anymore.

Comment: Yes, folders are separate and old folder is renamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was using the newest error corrected Soci library from github and not the stable download version.

Bests